# Return a void method using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, return-value, quicksort

I am trying to implement quick sort on array of Strings, but I can't figure out how to return an array of string from a void method. P.S.: Just in case I wanna inform you that all the other methods such as swap and partition are already implemented and I don't think that you need to see them. It is not an option to use any third party helper libraries.

```
public static String[] quicksort(String[] a)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length;
    quicksort_lomuto(a, low, high);
    return a; //<-- Here is the problem!!! What am I supposed to return?
}
public static void quicksort_lomuto(String[] a, int i, int j)
{
    if(j-i < 2) return;
    int k = partition_lomuto(a, i, j);
    quicksort_lomuto(a, i, k);
    quicksort_lomuto(a, k+1, j);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [code example at SE CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4022/java-implementation-of-quick-sort).

Comment: I'm not sure that it's an honorable thing to avoid the utilities.  They are often optimized beyond what a single mere programming team would bother with.  In addition they likely have over a decade of debugging in them, with a much larger audience trying to find the bugs.

Comment: In both methods you have an array passed in.  If you don't need to reallocate that then there's no need to pass it back.

Answer (score 1):

If you must have a `void` return, you can simply change the contents of the array. While the array parameter has been passed by value, that "value" is essentially a pointer to the array, not the full contents of the array. An example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[]{ "foo", "bar" };
    changeMyArray(arr);
    System.out.println(arr[0] + "," + arr[1]); // output is: foo,baz
 }

 private static void changeMyArray(String[] myArray) {
     myArray[1] = "baz";
 }
```

If you *set* the array parameter to something (`a = mumble`), that will not be reflected when returning from the method. But if you set the *contents* of the array to something (`a[i] = mumble`), it will.

You might not wish to mutate the input array. In that case, you could achieve the same solution with an "output parameter".

```
public static void quicksort_lomuto(String[] inputArray, int i, int j, String[] outputArray)
{
    if (outputArray == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("outputArray cannot be null");
    }
    if (outputArray.length != inputarray.length)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "outputArray must be the same length as inputArray");
    }
    /* sort inputArray, putting values into outputArray */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide not to return any new values, then your only means of manipulating the values such that the new arrangements are reachable outside of the block is to rearrange the inner contents of the objects being passed to the function.

For example, I could implement a

```
sort(int[] values)
```

function with a block that looks like

```
if (values[x] > values[y]) {
   int temp = values[x];
   values[x] = values[y];
   values[y] = temp;
}
...
```

and now the array that was passed through the parameter list will be different after the method completes.

This is a pretty poor programming style / practice; however, it is necessary in the rare cases where moving your collection or generating a new collection of data is undesirable.  Those are really rare corner cases in computer science, but they do occur with data sets in the Terabyte range.

Also note that such techniques could permit the same data to be manipulated in two simultaneously executing calls, so if you are not using a single threaded solution, you need to partition the data and protect (by your own means) against destructive concurrent access.